# How to keep a always on top button on every window in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, titlebar

I want always on top button like in kde plasma double up arrow in every windows titlebar.
[image]

Comment: which is your DE? gnome?

Comment: ofcourse gnome . I want the functionality of Kde plasma keep above in gnome.